# Getting error when login to android app using facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to login to my app using Facebook, but i got following errors on `logcat`. I am using [simple Facebook library](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook)

```
02-09 09:34:51.863: E/ActivityThread(4778): Failed to find provider info for   com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
02-09 09:35:12.074: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778): -----
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778): ERROR: SessionStatusCallback: exception=
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778): com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: The connection to the server was unsuccessful.
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at com.facebook.Session.handleAuthorizationResult(Session.java:1079)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at com.facebook.Session.onActivityResult(Session.java:554)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook.onActivityResult(SimpleFacebook.java:1358)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at com.ajmal.facebooktest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:122)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-09 09:35:12.093: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 09:35:12.173: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778): java.lang.Throwable
02-09 09:35:12.173: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at com.sromku.simple.fb.utils.Logger.getStackTrace(Logger.java:84)
02-09 09:35:12.173: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at com.sromku.simple.fb.utils.Logger.logError(Logger.java:68)
02-09 09:35:12.173: E/com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook(4778):    at com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook.logError(SimpleFacebook.java:2036)
```

it is the login function executed at the time of login.But at the time of login it raise an exception:the connection to the server was unsuccessfull.Earlier it works fine for me but yesterday onwards it is not working and got above logcat response.

```
 private void login()
{
    mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            mSimpleFacebook.login(mOnLoginListener);
        }
    });
}


private OnLoginListener mOnLoginListener = new OnLoginListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onFail(String reason)
    {
        mTextStatus.setText(reason);

    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable throwable)
    {
        mTextStatus.setText("Exception: " + throwable.getMessage());

    }

    @Override
    public void onThinking()
    {

        mTextStatus.setText("Thinking...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogin()
    {

        mTextStatus.setText("Logged in");
        preference.edit().putBoolean("isFirstTime", false);
        Properties properties = new Properties.Builder()
                .add(Properties.ID)
                .add(Properties.FIRST_NAME)
                .add(Properties.EMAIL)
                .build();
        mSimpleFacebook.getProfile(properties, onProfileRequestListener);


    }
```

Comment: Failed to find provider info for.... seems you are missing some required parameter

Comment: There's no code here to diagnose, just a stacktrace.  If you provide some of your code, you'll have a better chance of getting a useful response.

Comment: Posting a stack dump with nothing else (like the code that caused this) is about as useful as saying "my stove is on fire" and posting a picture of the flames.

Comment: when i click login button it raise exception:**the connection to the server was unsuccessfull**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a long shot, but do you have permissions for NETWORK in your manifest file? It's the only thing I can think of as far as why it couldn't connect...

Comment: yeah i have permission for NETWORK in my manifest file.

Comment: perhaps share the code where you're logging into the facebook app then. As Nambari pointed out, it looks like there's a blank for some reason that probably shouldn't be blank.

Comment: Sorry. The problem was in the emulator that it was not having internet access.